# Gedit syntax highlighting won't work for a new langauge

Tags: gnome, gedit

I am trying to create a new language definition for Gedit. The language is called nesC, and it is basically derived from C, sharing the C structure as a result.

I followed instructions on the Gnome wiki on how to create a new language.

I copied the c.lang file and pasted it to `~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs`, and then made all necessary changes to the file to convert C to nesC.

The problem is that, when I open a file with the extension `.nc`, it is still in plain black colour. However, if I go to View → Highlight Mode → Sources, the nesC option is there and is already selected, which means that Gedit is detecting the file type. In that case, why are there no colours? When I select C from the sources I get the colours.

I also created a mime type file as indicated in the Gnome wiki article on how to create a new language.

---

In the file, I changed `id=c` to `id=nesc`. If I change it back to `id=c`, then it works. Why should I not use `nesc`? The tutorial clearly changes the value (`id=foo`).

Comment: Can you please include a link to the syntax specification file in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should change **`id`** attribute in 2 places, in the main tag `<language>` and tag `<context>` (child of `<definitions>`):

```xml
…
<language id="nesc" _name="nesC" version="2.0" _section="Source">
  <metadata>
    <property name="mimetypes">text/x-nesc</property>
    <property name="globs">*.nesc;*.nc</property>
  </metadata>
  …
```

and

```xml
  …
  <definitions>
    <context id="nesc">
      …
    </context>
  </definitions>
</language>`
```

(But I do not know how have you named mime-type.)